# Java Error - What am I doing wrong with this exponential?

Tags: java, exponential

Alright so I've got this piece of code:

```
blah = (26^0)*(1);
System.out.println(blah);
```

Which produces the output 26, when it should be equal to 1. What am I doing wrong? What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you're confusing the `^` operator.  In Java, the `^` operator does an exclusive-or operation.  To get a power, you need to use `Math.pow(a,b)`

Answer (score 3):

In Java, the operator `^` is not exponentiate, but rather bitwise-xor. Anything `xor 0` is itself, so `26^0=26`, `26*1=26`

Answer (score 1):

`Math.pow(base, exponent)` works. The `^` means [Bitwise-XOR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#XOR).

So, you should use:

```
blah = Math.pow(26, 0) * 1;
System.out.println(blah);
```

Answer (score 0):

As the previous responses said you are actually doing a bitwise XOR (which results in 26) and then multiplying by 1. See [Bitwise and Bit Shift Operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html) and [Summary of Operators](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) for more info. You should be using Math.pow(base, exponent) so Math.pow(26.0, 0.0) as described in the [Math api](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html)